# Is it possible to transport many (up to 12) bikes using some sort of auto-trailer?

Tags: accessories, cargo, car-rack, transport-by-car

I would like to be able to use a trailer, either open-air or enclosed to transport multiple bicycles at the same time.  When I google hitch racks the maximum is 5...I am looking for a towable option...do these exist? Where can I find one?  Could I make one?

Comment: Did you try asking at a car shop? They may know best what auto-trailers exist. Personally, I think you may need a (small) bus to carry that much bikes.

Comment: If you google Image search "uplift trailer" you'll see loads! I reckon there will be someone offering hireable trailers. You might be able to purchase one second-hand from an uplift service that deals with Downhill Mountain Bikers.

Answer (score 5):

Where I live it is common for commercial operator to purpose build trailers for carrying bikes such as [these](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=bicycle%20transporting%20trailer&client=firefox-a&hs=Tpk&hl=en&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=n6JvUfyjJI2fiAeV3IGwAg&sqi=2&ved=0CDkQsAQ&biw=1280&bih=855).

The other option I have seen is custom bike racks for back of any flatdeck trailer or trucks.

One event here has over 1000 entrants to a relay - they need to transport 1500 bikes on the day, up to 100km..... So it's certainly doable.... I am glad I don't do their logistics planning...

Comment: I especially like the one on the 12th row down, on the left.

Comment: My browser dimensions are different - but I can guess which one :)

Answer (score 1):

I once constructed a trailer that could in theory handle 8 bikes.  Used it for family biking and for Boy Scout activities.  I used a standard 4x8 utility trailer as the base, and added removable uprights that the bikes could be strapped to.

The hard part is finding some sort of mounting scheme that can accommodate bikes of different sizes and styles (and do so reasonably cheaply).

Answer (score 1):

Check out huckwagons. Might be exactly what you wanted.

http://huckwagons.com/#trailers-section

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. [We prefer answers on this site to be self-contained](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). That way, the answer is still valid if the link dies. Please use the [edit] button to summarize the information is contained in the linked content within the body of your answer. Otherwise, it is likely to be downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. With a trailer, you can do just about anything you want. With a powerful enough vehicle, you could tow 120 bikes if you felt like it and had the money to build the trailer.

Go to a northern tool, fleet farm, or some similar store that sells trailer parts, and you can build up a trailer as big as you need.

You can use parts like these: http://yakima.com/shop/bike/truck-bed/blockhead to provide fork mounts for your bikes. Otherwise, you can fabricate fixtures that can hold the bikes with front wheels attached.